# Convert Json Object to Array in JS

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel-5.3

I convert Array in php by json_encode and send to JS.

I want convert this json:

```
[{"category_id":4},{"category_id":2},{"category_id":3}]
```

to:

```
['3','2','4']
```

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Did one of the below answers solve your issue?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `map` method.

```js
let array=[{"category_id":4},{"category_id":2},{"category_id":3}]
array=array.map(function(item){
  return item.category_id.toString();
});
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code :

```
var myObj = [{"category_id":4},{"category_id":2},{"category_id":3}]

var yourArray = myObj.map(function(value, index) {return value.category_id;})
```

I think this should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [{"category_id":4},{"category_id":2},{"category_id":3}];
var id = [];
for(var i in data)
{
     id.push(data[i].category_id);
}
console.log(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var a = [{"category_id":4},{"category_id":2},{"category_id":3}];

var b=[];

for(let i of a){

b.push(i.category_id);

}

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array=[{"category_id":4},{"category_id":2},{"category_id":3}]
array=array.map(function(item){
  return item.category_id.toString();
});
console.log(array);
```

I json Pass In php to JS with variable $category
bu in JS `var array= <?php echo $category; ?>` 
error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier